# How do I make pyinstaller include my database?

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt4, pyinstaller

I've got a PyQt4 application which makes use of sqlite3. I have two seperate files currently: a .py file and a .db file. Originally I took the .py file and tried to create an executable just using that thinking maybe it would link somehow but when I run the .exe it breaks when it gets to database related code. How do I get pyinstaller to include the database as well?

Answer (score 4):

[This post](https://elc.github.io/posts/executable-flask-pyinstaller/#solution) helped me. Basically, you can run the pyinstaller command with arguments as follows (assuming your script is `script.py` and your database is `database.db`):

```
pyinstaller -w --add-data "database.db;." script.py
```

This will first create a `.spec` file that lists `database.db` as a file to be included in your build. The created `.spec` file will then be used to run the build.

As explained [here](https://elc.github.io/posts/executable-flask-pyinstaller/#tutorial), the -w option prevents a console from being displayed when you run the `.exe` file that will be created.

---- **Alternatively** ----

According to [the docs](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html), you can first create just the `.spec` file and then modify it to list the data files that should be included. The `.spec` file for `script.py` is created using:

```
pyi-makespec script.py
```

Then, within the `.spec` file created, you can modify the `datas` field:

```py
a = Analysis(...
    datas=[ ('database.db', '.') ],
    ...
)
```

This assumes that `database.db` is in the root folder. If not, you will need to include the path. The `'.'` specifies where you want the database file to be located in the build (in this case, `'.'` is the root folder). To include more files, you can add more tuples `('<file>', '<path>')` to the `datas` list.

Comment: Hello @Joel Oduro-Afriyie, I created a Python exe file which U built with Microsoft SQL database. The app runs fine and connects to the database on the system I used in freezing it but when deployed to other systems, it doesn't get connected to the database. I was informed for the app to work fine on other systems, I would need to ensure those systems have Microsoft SQL too. Now I'm considering using SQLite database and have started creating the tables. I do hope my app will open well on other system with the database accessed without issue?

Comment: Hi @CEO, I believe that should work. SQLite is Python's internal database, so including an sqlite database in your application should make it run without having to depend on an external database on the host system.

Comment: Hello @Joel Oduro, I also recently noticed that freezing the file with onefile command makes the database inaccessible when deployed and run on another system. It would only work fine in the source system unless I don't use the --onefile command when pyinstalling. This means that in the build and dist folder, another folder containing the .exe file and other distributions and I would need to pack everything to the receiving system

Comment: Hello @Joel Oduro, please can I apply the code you gave above when using Microsoft sql server database? If yes, how do I locate the database in my system? I have tried using the searchbar to find it, but to no avail. I built an app with Python and MSSQL, they run fine on the system I used in creating the .exe file but when deployed to other systems, the database becomes inaccessible. I wish to ask this on a new post but I'm restricted by the admins and moderators here.

Comment: Is there a way to set this up so that different executables used for specific operating systems (win/linux/mac) can use the same database?

Comment: @CodedContainer, I'm not sure about that. Perhaps a workaround could be to host your database on some server and write your application to communicate with that server.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a specfile. Have a look at the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-data-files).

pyinstaller creates those file automatically. You just need to edit it. Have a look at the example from the docs. To add a README file you just need to add a tuple (source, destination) to 'datas':

```
a = Analysis(...
 datas=[ ('src/README.txt', '.') ],
 ...
 )
```

Comment: I'm adding my .db file to the Datas list and saving it but it's still not working for some reason. I'll add what I'm doing to the question.

Comment: Oh I actually got it to work but the console opens now. Do you know which stage I pass in --windowed?

Comment: For some reason it's not working again. Do you know on which command I pass in the --windowed and --onefile options? pyi-makespec or pyinstaller myfile.spec?

Comment: I don't get why but sometimes when I build it it references the database and other times it doesn't.

Comment: afaik it should be `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed your_app.py`

Comment: try building your specfile with `py-Makespec --onefile --windowed ...` and running it with `pyi-build foobar.spec` (see [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/man/pyi-makespec.html) and [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html))

Comment: hi... please I'm in the situation as @WewLad, could you please share us your sollution?