# Database Not Working with Pyinstaller Executable for PyQt5

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I compiled some files having database connections to an executable and even to setup but whenever I run it on the machine everything worked except when it gets to an activity that involves database then it always crashes. I have been searching for many hours and I in fact came across a very similar question: [How do I make pyinstaller include my database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37483516/how-do-i-make-pyinstaller-include-my-database) However, I have tried one after the other the different solutions proffered in the post, yet, mine didn't work. Probably because that was PyQt4 and mine is PyQt5. I was originally using MySQL, when it didn't work I still changed to Sqlite3, and surprisingly it doesn't work too.

This is the way I am converting to executable: pyinstaller --onefile --windowed test.py

Thanks in advance

Comment: remove  `--onefile`

Comment: @eyllanesc When I removed --onefile I got this error message: Error loading Python DLL ':\Program Files (x86)\Installation Folder Name\python38.dll'. LoadLibrary: The specified module could not be found

Comment: Don't use python3.8 as pyinstaller has problems with recent versions of python, for example you should use python3.6

Comment: @eyllanesc OK, boss! So what should I do exactly? Reinstall a new python or setting up a virtual environment of some sort?

Comment: @eyllanesc it still didn't work. I have tried to uninstall my python 3.8 and installed several versions of 3.6 and even a version of 3.5, yet all never worked. It has now changed the python38.dll in the error message to python36.dll